# First English Renaissance play where women disguise as men?

Tags: history-of-literature, theater, english-renaissance-theater

In several of Shakespeare's plays, women disguise as men (for a variety of reasons). For example,

- In *The Merchant of Venice*, Portia disguises as a lawyer; Jessica disguises as a man when eloping with her non-Jewish lover.
- In *As You Like It*, Rosalind disguises as Ganymdede, and her friend Celia as Aliena.

[Philip Stubbes or Stubbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Stubbs), writing before the start of Shakespeare's career as a dramatist, criticised this type of crossdressing in his book *Anatomie of Abuses* (1583). So what was the first English Renaissance play that involved women disguising as men?

**Update** in response to various comments:

1. Crossdressing may have been a feature of a number of plays from classical antiquity, but this is only of limited relevance to my question. A thousand years passed between the end of classical antiquity and the beginning of the English Renaissance. The theatrical tradition had been interrupted; the most common types of plays in Medieval England were [mystery plays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_play) and [morality plays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morality_play), which were based on a Christian tradition and far removed from the ancient Greek and Roman plays.
2. Cross-dressing seems innocuous now (at least in the West), but this was not the case in Shakespeare's time.

   - There were [sumptuary laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumptuary_law) that regulated who could wear what types of clothes or materials; several such laws from the reign of Henry VIII were re-enacted in 1565. For example, only the nobility was allowed to wear imported woollen fabrics; only those with an income of £ 100 per year were allowed to wear satin, damask, silk, camlet or tafetta. The goal of these laws was to keep the "natural" class distinctions intact. (Source: G. Blakemore Evans, ed.: *Elizabethan-Jacobean Drama: A New Mermaid Background Book*. 1988. Pp. 129f.)
   - Cross-dressing was frowned upon; see e.g. [Deuteronomy 22:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+22&version=KJ21): "The woman shall not wear that which pertaineth unto a man, neither shall a man put on a woman’s garment; for all who do so are abomination unto the Lord thy God.". "Cross-dressing" could be as simple as women wearing [bodices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodice) done up with buttons (buttons were very "masculine") or a hat; people were shocked and complained you couldn't tell the sexes apart. (Source: Ruth Goodman: *How to Be a Tudor*. 2015. Pp. 67, 85.)

Comment: Related (a sort of converse to this question): [When did men dressed as women stop being the norm in English theatre?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2607/17)

Comment: Stories where a man disguises himself as a woman [go back to Greece and Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achilles_on_Skyros).

Comment: It was common in Italian theater before the first English theater was built. It may be hard to pinpoint a specific play in English, since I suspect it would likely have been a translation of a play like The Deceived Ones. I don't know the history of the English-language performances of that play.

Comment: I think Shakespeare was a pioneer of it in England because he was inspired by female characters in foreign contemporary plays and historical figures who dressed as men. In which case it was probably *The Merchant of Venice*.

Comment: @Fabjaja The examples I found predate Shakespeare's plays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more research, I found the answer to my question. According to *The Growth Of English Drama* by Arnold Wynne (p. 176),

> [George Peele's play] [*Sir Clyomon and Sir Clamydes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Clyomon_and_Sir_Clamydes) merits a passing notice if only because it contains the earliest known example of a girl disguised as a page, the Princess Neronis waiting upon her lover in that office.

Since the play was probably written around 1570, it predates John Lyly's play [*Gallathea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallathea), which was written around 1588, and in which two women disguise as men. (*Gallathea* was the earliest example I was aware of when I posted the question.)