# What was Shakespeare's inspiration for the several cross-dressing episodes in his plays?

Tags: william-shakespeare, inspiration

I've heard that Shakespeare borrowed ideas from the events and other literary works from the time. He uses cross-dressing as a major plot device in several plays. Where did this come from?

Comment: Note that in Shakespeare's own productions of his plays, all the actors were male. So you had men (or boys) pretending to be women pretending to be men.

Comment: Related: [When did men dressed as women stop being the norm in English theatre?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2607/17) As mikado says, cross-dressing was much more common in real life in Shakespeare's day - at least in theatre - than it is today.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. That can explain why there men played the roles of women. But tales like As You Like It and The Twelfth Night have cross-dressing in the core of the story itself.

Comment: I think Mikado's comment serves as the answer to this question. Here Shakespeare was exploiting a fact of the contemporary theatre, not borrowing from another literary work.

Answer (score 1):

Among Shakespeare's contemporaries, the motif of a woman disguising as a man had been used before, for example by George Peele in his play [*Sir Clyomon and Sir Clamydes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Clyomon_and_Sir_Clamydes), which was written around 1570 and by John Lyly in his play [*Gallathea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallathea) (around 1588). (See my [related question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5105/2191).)

In his diary, John Manningham had noted similarities between Shakespeare's *Twelfth Night* and the Italian play [*Gl'ingannati* / *The Deceived Ones*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deceived_Ones), which dates from 1531, predating Peele's and Lily's plays. (There is no hard evidence that Shakespeare knew this play, though.) The play introduces Lelia, dressed as a boy. According to Yasuo TAMAIZUMI, *Gl' Ingannati* contains the earliest example of a female page.

However, the motif of cross-dressing is much older than the Renaissance. For example, [Achilles on Skyros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achilles_on_Skyros) is a story available in Publius Papinius Statius's unfinished [*Achilleid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achilleid) in which Achilles disguises himself as a girl.

In summary, Shakespeare may have found inspiration in sources from Antiquity, from the Italian Renaissance or from contemporary works.

---

References:

- Accademia degli Intronati: [*Gl'Ingannati* / *The Deceived*](https://emothe.uv.es/biblioteca/textosEMOTHE/EMOTHE0136_TheDeceived.php)
- [*Gl’Ingannati*, an Italian play about twins and mistaken identity](https://www.bl.uk/collection-items/gl-ingannati-an-italian-play-about-twins-and-mistaken-identity), British Library.
- [The festival of Twelfth Night in John Manningham's diary](https://www.bl.uk/collection-items/the-festival-of-twelfth-night-in-john-manninghams-diary), British Library.
- Yasuo TAMAIZUMI: [On Shakespeare's Twelfth Night](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tja/74/3/74_131/_article/-char/en), *Transactions of the Japan Academy*, Volume 74 (2020) Issue 3.